# Gradle script not able to resolve artifactory

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I am using Gradle to access the Artifactory. Artifactory has the particular dependencies but somehow gradle is not able to send any request to Artifactory. Even I tried to clean the cache and run the `gradle build` command to fetch the file. But I didn't get any success. By gradle.build file is as following.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/gradle-plugins' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '2.0.12')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'artifactory'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    maven {
      url 'http://artifactory/repo'
    } 
}

group = 'com.locationlabs'
version = '1.1'

artifacts {
   archives file("${project.name}-${project.version}-jstest.txt")

}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'http://artifactory'
    publish {
       repository {
          repoKey = 'autotest' 
          username = 'rakesh.kumar'  
          password = 'password'
       }
       defaults {
          publishBuildInfo = true
          publishArtifacts = true
          publishPom = true
          publishIvy = false
       }
    }
}

artifactoryPublish {
   publishConfigs('archives')
}

dependencies {
  compile group: 'com.locationlabs', name: 'gradletest', version: '1.0', classifier: 'jstest', ext: 'txt'
 }
```

Whenever I run the gradle script it fails with the following exception and stacktrace.

```
akesh.kumar@rakesh:~/automation/gradletest$ gradle build --stacktrace
:compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.wrapException(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.access$000(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver$BrokenResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:127)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:458)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:203)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext$FileTreeConverter.convertInto(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext$FileTreeConverter.convertInto(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:182)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection$1.resolve(CompositeFileCollection.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.getSourceCollections(CompositeFileCollection.java:143)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileTree.getSourceCollections(CompositeFileTree.java:30)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.getFiles(CompositeFileCollection.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultFileSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileSnapshotter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.InputFilesChangedUpToDateRule.create(InputFilesChangedUpToDateRule.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CompositeUpToDateRule.create(CompositeUpToDateRule.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$HistoricExecution.calcCurrentState(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$HistoricExecution.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.ShortCircuitTaskArtifactStateRepository$ShortCircuitArtifactState.isUpToDate(ShortCircuitTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.FileCacheBroadcastTaskArtifactStateRepository$1.isUpToDate(FileCacheBroadcastTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:247)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.executeTask(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:192)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.doExecute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:177)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:83)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:36)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$1.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:111)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:126)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:109)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:155)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:110)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.execute(RunBuildAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.execute(RunBuildAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:20)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder$ConfigurationNode.getArtifacts(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:651)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.attachToParents(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:356)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder$ConfigurationNode.attachToParents(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:764)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder.assembleResult(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:140)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.create(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.create(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:34)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:126)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.resolve(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:236)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:456)
    ... 65 more


BUILD FAILED
```

One very strange thing is that the same script file works on the other machine but doesn't work on mine even though the other machine has the same configuration and setup.

I tried to search on internet but couldn't get any help.
Any kind of help is greatly appreciated here.

Comment: Are you making sure that the same Gradle version is used on both machines? The preferred way of enforcing this is to use the [Gradle Wrapper](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html).

Comment: Both machine have the same version of gradle.

Comment: When failing - do any requests from Gradle reach Artifactory? How do these requests look like?

Comment: Artifactory doesn't get any request :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen the very same NPE yesterday after I tried to change my project name inside *gradle.settings* (`rootProject.name = 'something'`). When I delete this line from *gradle.settings*, the exception disappears.

After some investigation and with the help of http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_to_get_the_latest_integration_version_number I finally found out that the reason is a sort of circular dependency, when my project depended on some module that transitively depends back on a module with the same group and project names as the "current" project.

Might this be your case? What is the name of your project? And what are the dependencies of `gradletest`? Please check whether your referenced `gradletest` module does not depend on your project. Or, if your project itself is named `gradletest`, that would definitely explain the error.

Comment: Yes in my case there was circular dependency, and Dependency resolver was throwing NullPointer exception. yesterday I figured out the problem. It make sense that project shouldn't be dependent on itself. Well I have suggested gradle to show warring or Error in such case.